# CompiledFunction crashes kernel

Tags: bugs, compile

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0**

---

This crashes my kernel

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}, {center, _Real, 1}, {point, _Real, 1}}, 
(1` + (x - 1`) Exp[-Norm[point - center] 10`]), 
RuntimeAttributes -> Listable][3`, {0`, 0`}, {{1`, 1`}, {{1`, 1`}}}]
```

Changing the input parameters doesn't seem to change anything.

Changing `` (x - 1`) `` to `x` or to `` (3` - 1`) `` solves it.

Passing a proper matrix `` {{1`, 1`}, {1`, 1`}} `` solves it too.

Removing the `` 10` `` solves it too

What could be going on?

Comment: http://www.ccu.cl/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/crush-big.jpg

Comment: What is going on is this is a bug. I filed a report with what diagnosis I was able to provide.

Comment: Here is something similar from before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262218/using-a-compiled-listable-function-on-non-tensor-lists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the compiled function is Listable, there's an attempt to evaluate it in parallel across different threads, and that's where the crash occurs.

Disabling the parallel evaluation works around the problem and stays in the virtual machine:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {center, _Real, 1}, {point, _Real, 1}}, 
    (1` + (x - 1`) Exp[-Norm[point - center] 10`]), 
    RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization->False];
cf[3`, {0`, 0`}, {{1`, 1`}, {{1`, 1`}}}]
```

Comment: @DanielLichtblau said this is a bug, and has already been reported. jfklein13 had also suggested in chat setting Parallelization->False explicitly. Silvia's suggestion also seems to work.
It would still be nice, if this can't be fixed, to have a better idea of the cases in which one runs the risk of meeting this bug

Answer (score 7):

Although I absolutely don't know what is going on at all, adding a `Print` before the real evaluation seems a possible working around in my Mathematica 9 64bit version.

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}, {center, _Real, 1}, {point, _Real, 1}},
  Print[];
  (1` + (x - 1`) Exp[-Norm[point - center] 10`]), 
  RuntimeAttributes -> Listable][3`, {0`, 0`}, {{1`, 1`}, {{1`, 1`}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Print[]` causes the compiled function to call `MainEvaluate`, so this is probably the cause.

Comment: @shrx It's possible. I don't have pre-10 version now, but maybe you can test your hypothesis by replacing the bytecode `{46, Function[{x, center, point}, Print[]], 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 6, 0, 17}` in compiled expression with something like `{46, Function[{}, Null], 6, 0, 17}`, see if the crash still happens.