# Compiled function crashes kernel when trying to list over different length arguments

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, compile

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

I'm trying to speed up a tally/binning operation that I have to run many times.

I have many lists of between 1 and 10 numbers from the range [1,5] and I want to `Tally` the number of each number and output that in a list.

```
randomdata = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 100000];
```

Here is my initial uncompiled implementation using `SparseArray`

```
f = Normal@SparseArray[Rule @@@ (Tally@#), 5] &
```

This works, here is a sample:

```
f{5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2}
output: {0, 3, 1, 3, 3}
```

I'm trying to speed this up with a compiled implementation.

```
fC = Compile[{{totally, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Module[{tally = Tally[totally], table = Table[0, {i, 5}]},
   table[[tally[[All, 1]]]] = tally[[All, 2]];
   table],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

This works on the sample

```
fC[{5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2}]
output: {0, 3, 1, 3, 3}
```

but if I do `f[randomdata]` the kernel crashes without an error message and I can't figure out what went wrong.

Alternatively, if all the inputs are the same length:

```
randomdata = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {100000, 5}];
fC[randomdata]
```

This works...

It seems that the problem comes down to list over multiple arguments where each one has a different length.

see a simpler example

```
totalC = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}}, Total[list], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

This works: `totalC /@ randomdata;`

This crashes: `totalC[randomdata];`

Comment: `fC/@ randomdata` seems to work, and `f[randomdata]` seems also not work on my computer.

Comment: I verified and filed a minimal-example bug report.

Comment: This has been fixed as of version 10.0.0.

Comment: @ilian did you want to post that as an answer with a minimal working example and I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks @s0rce, I think the answer already posted is fine. By the way, this was the same bug as http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a comment by @ilian, this has been fixed as of version 10.0.0. It certainly works in version 10.1, as we can see below:

```
$Version
(* 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) *)

fC[randomdata] == (fC /@ randomdata)
(* True *)

totalC /@ randomdata
totalC[randomdata]
```

[image]