# Listable compiled function crashes the kernel with "no more memory available"

Tags: bugs, compile, crash

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

I am trying to speed up a function that involves continued fractions. Since [`ContinuedFraction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFraction.html) cannot be compiled, and the alternative way with `Nestlist` of `FractionalPart` does not produce the same results due to `ContinuedFraction`'s internal algorithm for the choice of the number of terms, I think the best way is to compute the continued fractions and then pass the integer list to the compiled function. Here's what I did:

```
fc = Compile[{{z, _Real}, {xcf, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Fold[z/(#1 + #2) &, 0, 1/xcf]/z, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]
z = {-.5, .5}
xcf = Reverse /@ Rest /@ ContinuedFraction[{.123455, .546452}]
fc[z, xcf]
```

This approach [should work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1442/6849), however on my computer (*Mathematica* 10.0.2, Xubuntu 15.04), evaluating the compiled function over a list of arguments always crashes the kernel and sometimes displays this message:

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

Why doesn't it work and how to fix this?

By the way, I am trying to recreate a higher quality version of the ["Road to the Horizon"](http://linas.org/art-gallery/farey/fthumb.html) transformation of continued fractions from Linas Vepstas's math art gallery.

**Update**: Setting `Parallelization -> False` in the compiled function as per @Joel Klein's answer in [17971](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17971/6849) works, and it seems this is a confirmed bug. However, in my case it does not seem to be fixed as reported in that thread.

Comment: FWIW, it also crashes on *Mathematica* 9.0.1, but *not* on 8.0.4.

Comment: I can also confirm it crashes with Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: As a workaround, it does not crash for me if you change the type of `xcf` to `Real` and use `Parallelization -> False`.

Comment: @rcollyer is changing the type of `xcf` even necessary? See the update in my question, disabling parallelization alone prevents the crash (but slows down the execution).

Comment: Nope, not necessary. It appears I was changing two things at once, and did not isolate which actually caused it not to crash.

Comment: I'd be interested if the kernel crashes with Mathematica 8.04 if `Parallelization` is explicitly set to `True`. Can anyone check?

Comment: @shrx no, it does not.

Comment: I should say I didn't try this in 9.0.0 (I don't have it installed). So we do not know for sure that this appeared only in 9.0.1.

Comment: Bug reported internally. Thank you!

Comment: @OleksandrR. you are right, I edited the notice.

Comment: @shrx 9.0.0 is correct. I checked before making my edit.

Comment: Fixed in the development version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This bug was speedily confirmed...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/listable-compiled-function-crashes-the-kernel-with-no-more-memory-available/97228#comment246381_90081)

> Bug reported internally. Thank you! –  [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/) Aug 7 at 15:22

[and fixed...internally at least.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/listable-compiled-function-crashes-the-kernel-with-no-more-memory-available/97228#comment248122_90081)

> Fixed in the development version. –  [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/) Aug 11 at 15:16

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not intended to address the bug described in the OP. Rather, my goal is to address

> Since `ContinuedFraction` cannot be compiled...

I don't know the exact specifics of what goes on inside `ContinuedFraction[]`, so the implementation I am about to present will slightly differ in the results. Nevertheless, I think it would be useful for me to present the algorithm I use on non-*Mathematica* systems.

The following algorithm is due to [Pyzalski and Vala](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0907026). Their algorithm is based on the elementary algorithm for generating the terms of a simple continued fraction; the wrinkle is in their choice of termination criterion for stopping the iteration. You can read their paper for more details. Here is a compiled routine implementing their algorithm:

```
ccf = With[{m = 1*^6}, Compile[{{x, _Real}},
           Module[{e = 1/m/(2 m - 1), d, f, h, n, nb, r, s, v, w},
                  r = IntegerPart[x]; s = Sign[x]; w = v = Abs[x - r];
                  f = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
                  nb = Internal`Bag[{r}];
                  While[True, h = 1/v; r = Floor[h];
                        Internal`StuffBag[nb, s r];
                        f = f.{{0, 1}, {1, r}};
                        {n, d} = f[[All, 2]];
                        If[Abs[w - n/d] >= e, v = h - r, Break[]]];
                  Internal`BagPart[nb, All]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];
```

`m` is an adjustable parameter that controls the termination criterion; crudely stated, `ccf` stops when the denominator of the CF convergent being considered has $\approx\log_{10}(\mathtt m)$ digits.

Test:

```
ccf[{0.123455, 0.546452}]
   {{0, 8, 9, 1, 84, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 2, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3, 1}}

ContinuedFraction[{0.123455, 0.546452}]
   {{0, 8, 9, 1, 84, 4}, {0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 2, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3, 1}}

ContinuedFraction[N[π]]
   {3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14}

ccf[N[π]]
   {3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3}
```

Even with the slight differences, I think `ccf[]` does a good job.

(Note that with some work, one can modify `ccf[]` to be a compiled substitute for `Convergents[]`.)