# Mathematica MathKernel memory consumption

Tags: compile

I recognised that for some reason when I use `Compile` and use a C-compiler the memory consumption of Mathematica's MathKernel is very large even after I reset all the stored data or variables with `` Clear["Global`*"] ``.

I thought the aforementioned command would reset just everything that is stored inside the kernel. Why is Mathematica still occupying a huge amount of memory. Is the overhead of `Compile` so big and what can I do to improve it?

**[Edit]**

My problem seems to be related to the `Parallelization` option within `Compile`. If enter my arguments as follows

```
a=1;
b=1;
c=1;
cfun[a,b,c]
```

the huge overhead during the evaluation of `cfun` is removed after calling `cfun` and only the output of cfun occupies memory (no matter the value of the `Parallelization` option within compile).

However, if I call `Parallelization->True` together with `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and insert the arguments as follows

```
n=1;
a=Table[1,{n}];
b=Table[1,{n}];
c=1Table[1,{n}]
cfun[a,b,c]
```

then even for `n=1` a huge overhead is produced that eventually occupies more memory than the actual output of cfun. The goal why I wanted to write the arguments as lists and use the `listable` attribute was to use effective parallelization when increasing `n` to higher integers like `n=3`.

So for my program, with `Parallelization->False` and the latter technique of entering the arguments, my program occupies eventually only 4.9% of my memory. Setting `Parallelization->True` with the same length of output it consumes 19.3% of my memory.

This is a remarkable huge overhead when calling the `Parallelization` option. Is there any way to improve it, or is this option simply like a black box?

**[Edit2]**

I think this thread might be slightly related to my problem:

[Listable compiled function crashes the kernel with "no more memory available"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/listable-compiled-function-crashes-the-kernel-with-no-more-memory-available/97228#comment246381_90081)

Comment: If you genuinely want to reset everything in the kernel I would use `Quit`.

Comment: `Quit` quits the kernel yes. But I want to find out what is causing the huge memory consumption. Are there any commands to see what Mathematica stores and where it is stored? Is it necessary for `Compile` to store something somewhere which I am not aware of? Or should `Compile` only occupy as much memory as the output of the compiled function requires?

Comment: Ok, so if I use `$HistoryLength = 0` and then clear my compiled function `cfun` then all the memory seems to be accessible again. Within my `Compile` I use a `Block` environment with many local variables. Is there a way to just clear everything within my compiled function after using it, but keeping the function itself available? (if I use clear I need to re-input the function again if I want to use it again)

Comment: See my [Edit] in the OP. I figured out that my problem is related to the `Parallelization` option within compiled.

Comment: Without a simple example to test, it is hard to say what happens on your machine.